# Is there a typical way to handle separate configurations for different tomcat instances in a Java app?

Tags: java, tomcat

Our system is split up into different environments, each one as a separate Tomcat instance.

- Development (Windows)
- QA: Accessed by our QA department (Linux)
- Production: Live site, accessible to customers. (Linux)

Each of these environments rely on separate databases, and several other web services. This means we need to keep track of the various URLs, usernames, and passwords that are all different. Many of these settings are shared across several apps, so it would be ideal to have them all in one place to remove duplication.

Right now we have config files in the application itself. We use Maven profiles to fill in the different config settings when we build the app. But this is clumsy because we have to build a different WAR for each environment.

Where is a good place to store the config files so that we can deploy the same WAR file to each server?

---

I've done a fair amount of research on this already. But I haven't found an solution that completely makes sense to me yet.

### Separate Config Directory

Define a directory to hold config files. Such as `/opt/config` on linux.

I like this idea, but how do I tell Tomcat where this directory is? I see references to `context.xml`, but every example I've seen puts the context.xml in the META-INF folder inside the WAR. Is there a way to configure this outside the WAR?

### System Property to define environment

This involves setting a system property, and then using some sort of if/else or switching logic to load the appropriate config file. This seems workable, but a bit messy. But where/how do you set this property? I typically start tomcat with `./startup.sh`. Do I add arguments to that command or is there another configuration somewhere?

### JNDI

I don't think this is an option for us. Every tutorial I've looked at for this seems to be dependent on LDAP or something similar. To my knowledge we don't have that available to us, and it seems like too much overhead to get set up for only a half-dozen config files.

Comment: It may be overkill for you, but I like [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/).

Comment: In my last job, we wrote out the properties to Tomcat's config dir, which is seen by the app.  Probably not the best solution, but it worked for us.  The other option would be to pass in the properties path via a -D parameter on the JVM.

Comment: You don't need LDAP to do JNDI.  You do need to fiddle with tomcat configs, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with my team on this and we came up with what we feel is a cleaner approach. While every tutorial I found put the context.xml inside the WAR, it can also be placed in the conf folder of the Tomcat directory.

This works for us as all our servers are Tomcat based. So each server can have it's own context.xml which has a property pointing to the config folder on that particular server.

Answer (score 1):

Use system property that refers to the location where your configuration file or directory is located. In this case you can manage different environment easily and no if/else logic is needed.

You application can have hard coded value of config file path, that will allow running application without any additional system property. The application however should fail to start if mandatory data is not found.

Concerning to partial sharing of data among environments. 
You can split your data into several files by categories. Some files will be shared, some other different for different environments. You can even develop your own mechanism of references between data files.

However better approach is using some ready-to-use packages. For example Spring framework supports very flexible configuration mechanism. However if you already have Spring-less application introducing this framework for configuration only seems like an overkill. In this case take a look on [Apache Commons Configuration package](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/).